# How can I infinitely wait for an element to be clickable in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This feature is available in Puppeteer which allows passing 0 as timeout which is infinite. But the same is not available in Selenium. Is there any custom function that you guys know?

P.S. I need this function because I want to test something on my server and the timeout can be variable like sometimes it can take the 30s or sometimes 30m.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing infinite wait kind of concept in Selenium. Because this is not the ideal case to wait something for infinite time (1Minute, 1Hour, 1Day, 1Month, 1Year... and so on).

The certain condition should be fulfill within specific time. So one thing you can do is provide maximum threshold wait time. Selenium will continuously check whether your element be clickable until maximum threshold value reached.

As per Selenium documentation:

> ExplicitWait allow your code to halt program execution, or freeze the
>   thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The condition is
>   called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the wait is
>   elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns a falsy
>   value, it will keep trying and waiting.

Comment: @Vyom, is this answer resolved your problem ? If yes then accept it by click tick mark on answer below vote count so it can be helpful for others. Still have query then feel free to ask ?